# How to change the back bar button title on xamarin IOS Native

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

Iam new in xamarin IOS native , I want to change the back bar item name .[image]

I tried this NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem.Title = "Promotions";  on ViewDidLoad();, but i got an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify current viewController's back item's name, you should set it in the previous viewController. Customize a new UIBarButtonItem in the past viewController:

```
NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Promotions", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
```